# Migrate SSE2 to Arm NEON intrinsincs

Tags: kinect, neon, sse2

I have the following code in SSE2 intrinsincs. It processes input from a Kinect.

```
__m128i md = _mm_setr_epi16((r0<<3)  | (r1>>5), ((r1<<6)  | (r2>>2) ), ((r2<<9)  | (r3<<1) | (r4>>7) ), ((r4<<4)  | (r5>>4) ), ((r5<<7)  | (r6>>1) ),((r6<<10) | (r7<<2) | (r8>>6) ), ((r8<<5)  | (r9>>3) ), ((r9<<8)  | (r10)   ));
md = _mm_and_si128(md, mmask);
__m128i mz = _mm_load_si128((__m128i *) &depth_ref_z[i]);
__m128i mZ = _mm_load_si128((__m128i *) &depth_ref_Z[i]);
mz = _mm_cmpgt_epi16(md, mz);
mZ = _mm_cmpgt_epi16(mZ, md);
mz = _mm_and_si128(mz, mZ);
md = _mm_and_si128(mz, md);
_mm_store_si128((__m128i *) frame,md)
if(_mm_movemask_epi8(mz)){ ... }
```

This basically unpacks 11 uint8_t (r0-r10) to 8 uint16_t in an SSE register(mmask is constant and created previously). It then loads two more registers with the corresponding elements from two arrays that serve as bounds. It checks them and creates a register which has the elements that don't fit in the criteria zeroed out. It then stores them and goes to further process each element. The movemask serves as a nice optimization when none of the elements pass in which case the processing can be skipped.

This works nice and now I want to port it to NEON as well. Most of it is straightforward except two parts. Looking at the assembler output(gcc) from the SSE2 code I see that instead of doing 8 uint16_t moves in _mm_setr_epi16 it shifts and ors them into uint32_t and finally does 4 moves. That seems efficient and since the compiler takes care of it I didn't change the code. Should I apply that manually in the NEON case? Instead of 8 vsetq_lane_u16 do the shifting and perform 4 vsetq_lane_u32? Will I have any issues with endianess and will it be worthwhile?

The final part is the movemask as I haven't been able to find an equivalent. Can anyone suggest something?

Answer (score 1):

I'd prefer starting with plain C code instead of SSE2; there might be optimization opportunities not easily seen at this low level